# Show a number as binary in Wolfram Alpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha

Is there any way to see a number as it's individual bits (i.e. base 2) in Wolfram Alpha?

For example, given the number `255`, it should show: `11111111`

Similarly, the number `4` can be shown as: `100`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just guessed, and found out that you can use `<number> as base 2`.

Example: `255 as base 2` outputs: `11111111`<sub>`2`</sub>.

Other forms that work as well:

- 255 as base2
- 255 base 2
- convert 255 to base 2
- 255 to binary
- 255 to base 2

Answer (score 3):

You can do the same with [Google](http://www.google.no/search?q=255+in+base+2) by using `<number> in base 2`.